# Javascript pattern for quick lookup of multiple select behaviors?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Say you have three `SELECT` elements, each with a variable number of options.

```
<select id="a">
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select id="b">
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="c">
   <option value="0">Zero</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
   <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

And let's say there are several different actions you can take depending on the pattern of options chosen. If you have `a1 + b2 + c5` it would do something different from `a2 + b1 + c1`. Some patterns might display or hide still other `SELECT` controls.

I've seen a lot of code that has multi-level `if/else` statements to cover all the permutations, but it's always looked messy and hard to maintain.

Another way to do this might involve creating a hash table, with properties named with string representations of the combinations:

```
function foo() {
   // statements
}
function bar() {
   // statements
}
var selectPatterns = {
    'a1b2c5' : foo,
    // ... other properties and function references
    'a2b1c1' : bar
    // ... possibly still more properties and function references
};
```

And this involves a function that determines the choices made and locates the correct property of `selectPatterns` to call as well as one that gets the value of each `SELECT`:

```
function getSelectValue(id) {
   var sel = document.getElementById(id);
   return id + sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
} 

function abcExecute () {
   var propName = getSelectedValue('a') + getSelectedValue('b') + getSelectedValue('c'); 

   selectPatterns[propName]();
}
```

The latter function runs `foo()` in the case of 'a1b2c5' and `bar()` in the case of 'a2b1c1'.

**What I want to know is whether this is a good design pattern to use, or if there are other, better ways to assign behaviors based on multiple input conditions.**

Answer (score 0):

Would there be one distinct function per permutation, or might several permutations call the `foo` function?

If the former, I prefer your method to using `if/else` or `switch`.

If the latter, I might do something like this on your last line:

`if('a1b2c5 a3b0c3 a2b2c5'.indexOf(propName) > -1) foo()`.

That may reduce your program's memory usage, and a string lookup may be faster than an object lookup.

Comment: A function could be shared by multiple properties, but wouldn't have to be.

Comment: In that case, there may not be a one-size-fits-all answer.  In your example, there are 60 permutations.  If each referenced a different function, your `selectPatterns` object strategy may be as good as any.  If 30 referenced `foo()` and the other 30 referenced `bar()`, my `indexOf` strategy may be more effective.    Anything in the middle may be more subjective, as a balance between speed, memory usage, and ease of maintenance.